# Hard wrapping in vim without joining

Tags: vim, text-formatting, word-wrap

Vim newbie here.  How can I hard wrap plain text in vim (inserting actual linebreaks), respecting word boundaries, *without joining existing lines*?

For example, given this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

- Nulla cursus accumsan faucibus.
- Donec dapibus dignissim ullamcorper.

Integer
nec
malesuada
diam.
```

I'd like to get (with textwidth=30):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.

- Nulla cursus accumsan
  faucibus.
- Donec dapibus dignissim
  ullamcorper.

Integer
nec
malesuada
diam.
```

instead of this (which I can get with `gggqG`)

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.

- Nulla cursus accumsan
  faucibus.
- Donec dapibus dignissim
  ullamcorper.

Integer nec malesuada diam.
```

<s>Also, for bonus points: when I create a brand new buffer, I get different wrapping behavior (lines beginning with - aren't wrapped specially) than when I open a file ending in .txt.</s>  What controls this?  I don't notice any difference in the output of `:set filetype?` or `:filetype`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the first question, use

```
:%normal gqq
```

That will execute `gqq` on each line individually.

I don't know the answer to the second question, but it could be the result of an autocommand triggered by the .txt suffix that changes `'formatoptions'` or `'comments'` without setting the `'filetype'`. You can execute

```
:verbose set fo? com?
```

to see where those options were set last. Some GNU/Linux distributions put their own Vim configuration commands in /etc/vimrc or /usr/share/vim/vimrc.

Comment: Thanks! Oddly it doesn't do the whole file; it stops 70% of the way through and says "6 more lines" (though there's far more than 6 lines remaining). Repeating the command takes it to 95% and says "5 more lines", and once more completes the file.  There's no indication that any error occurred to make it stop.

Comment: Try this instead then: `:g/./normal gqq`. I *think* that `%` applies the command to every line as it goes, whereas `g/pattern/` marks each matching line first, then goes back and applies the command to each marked line. Because your command is changing the number of lines in the file, the `g/pattern/` may work better.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the "different wrapping behavior" I mentioned in my question--user error, I guess.  And the g/./ approach did work on the entire file, this time with the message "84 more lines"--which I guess is the number of lines added to the file, not number of lines remaining or anything.  Thanks!