# Hard line wrapping in vim without joining in insert mode

Tags: vim, text-formatting, word-wrap

Very new to vim.  Found a useful post [here](https://agilesysadmin.net/how-to-manage-long-lines-in-vim/) that explains how to get automatic hard line breaks while in insert mode.

This had unintended consequences.  For example, suppose I start a new .txt file.  While in insert mode, I type

```
a
```

Still in insert mode, I hit return and type 'b'.  What appears is not

```
a
b
```

but

```
a b
```

When I set

```
set: formatoptions-=a
```

This unintended behavior stops, as do the intended line breaks.

I'd like to keep the latter without the former.  There seemed to be a related  [question](https://superuser.com/questions/240699/hard-wrapping-in-vim-without-joining) that focuses on the same issue, but for re-formatting existing text.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-formatting first sounds like a great feature, but it has many caveats, so I personally find it helpful only for very few editing tasks.

[`:help auto-format`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#auto-format) offers good advice to make this workable. In particular:

> - You need to properly define paragraphs.  The simplest is paragraphs that are
>     separated by a blank line.  When there is no separating blank line, consider
>     using the 'w' flag and adding a space at the end of each line in the
>     paragraphs except the last one.

So, `:setlocal formatoptions+=w` and then it'll work as you expect. (But each line inside a paragraph will end with a trailing space!)

Comment: Thank you very much!!  Tried this and it worked great.  The auto-format documentation was also very helpful -- will check there before asking questions in the future.  Thanks again!

Comment: Alright, nice. Please don't forget to accept the answer (by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it)!